# going against REST conventions in Rails forms

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, rest

Let me be clearer.

my app has two tables/models:  Bikes and Cars

I have a form on page views/cars/index

However, even though the form is in views/cars/index, it has attributes (:pedals and :handlebars) for the Bikes table.

1) Which controller should the form on cars/index with attributes for the Bikes model be submitted to ?

2) What does the form have to look like (in terms of submitting from a view in the Cars index to Bikes model?  <%= form_for(@car) do |f| %>  OR  <%= form_for(@bike) do |f| %>

3) What changes do I have to make to the route when I submit from the index of views/cars/index to insert data into the bikes table?  why did I get a missing controller error message when I tried the solution posted by @axsuul

### below this line is an earlier (maybe less clear) attempt to explain the problem but i don't think it was clear

this is a form that I have in views/cars/new.html.erb

```
<%= form_for(@car) do |f| %>
  <% if @car.errors.any? %>
```

and the results are visible in views/cars/show and views/cars/index

However, if I want to submit a form from  `views/cars/index` (Yes I know you don't usually submit from index), and then have it show in a completely different model `views/bikes/index`, what do I have to change to this?

```
<%= form_for(@car) do |f| %>
      <% if @car.errors.any? %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understand your question right you have a form for creating bikes on your cars/index page.

In that case, create a new bike in the cars controllers index action,

```
class CarsController < ApplicationController
  ...
  def index
    @cars = Car.all
    @bike = Bike.new
  end
  ...
end
```

and use that to create the form,

```
<%= form_for(@bike) do |f| %>
...
```

which left like that will be handled by bikes controllers create action.

I still consider this RESTful...

Comment: when you say this "will be handled by bikes controllers create action." is that because you have Bike.new in the index page of cars_controller?

Comment: No, `form_for(@bike)` will POST to /bikes unless you tell it otherwise and that should be routed to bikes controllers create action in a RESTful design.

Comment: so that means I have to receive it in the create action of Bike, like this... @bike = Bike.new(params[:bike])  ... if I want to then display the results somewhere?

Comment: after the bike is created (or couldn't be created) `redirect_to some_path`

Comment: I tried what you suggested but it's not saving data. If you have time, please see this question here (names of models are different but concept/intention same) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8370040/not-saving-no-error-message

Answer (score 1):

You can choose whatever URL you want to submit to by doing

```
<%= form_for(@car), :url => create_car_path do |f| %>
```

for the route

```
post '/views/cars/index', "cars#index", :as => :create_car
```

If you are asking to customize which view to render after submitting, you do that in the controller

```
def index
  @car = Car.new(params[:car])

  if @car.save
    render 'bikes/index'

  end

end
```

---

Hmm, so from what you explained, you are probably looking for something along the lines of

`bikes_controller.rb`

```
def create
  @bike = Bike.new(params[:bike])

  if @bike.save
    redirect_to cars_path and return  # this should go back to /cars if successful
  end

  render 'cars/index'   # or render /views/cars/index.html.erb
end
```

`cars_controller.rb`

```
def index
  @bike = Bike.new 
end
```

`index.html.erb`

```
<%= form_for @bike, :url => create_bike_path do |f| %>
```

`routes.rb`

```
get 'cars' => "cars#index", :as => :cars
post 'cars' => "bikes#create", :as => :create_bike
```

Comment: question: when you write form_for(@car) does the instance variable "@car" have to be the same as teh controller you're submitting to, or could you just have easily done form_for(@bento) and still submitted it to the "car" controller?

Comment: I couldn't get it to work. The error message said missing: controller in the routes file.