# Not saving, no error message

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

On form submission, it's telling me that it was successfully created but it's not showing any data that was submitted. The database is empty. It's showing "null" values and the same on the actual screen where I should be able to edit the data.  Here's a screenshot

[image]

Update: I think the problem is that it's making a GET request but I don't know how to fix it. Here's a screen shot of my server doing a get when I clicked the submit
[image: server doing a get]

---

**Here's the set up**

In the index action of results_controller.rb, I have

```
    def index
    @results = Result.all
    @blob = Sex.new            //==@blob = Sex.new is the one I'm focussing on...
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.xml  { render :xml => @results }


    end
  end
```

**In views/results/index, I have the form**

```
<`%= form_for(@blob) do |f| %>`

<div class="field">
    <b>1. solicitor exam was fixed?:</b><br/>
    <%= f.label(:solicitorcurve, "it was cooked") %>
    <%= f.radio_button(:solicitorcurve, "t") %> </br>
  </div>  
  <div class="field">

   <%= f.label(:solicitorcurve, "no it was ok") %>
    <%= f.radio_button(:solicitorcurve, "f") %>
   </div>  

    <div class="field">
    <%= f.label(:draftingteach, "i give the teaching a grade of _ on a scale of 1 to 6") %>
    <%= f.select:draftingteach, 1..6 %> </br>
    </div>
```

**In the create action of sexes_controller.rb i have**

```
def create

    @sex = Sex.new(params[:blob])
    respond_to do |format|
      if @sex.save
        format.html { redirect_to(@sex, :notice => 'Sex was successfully created.') }
        format.xml  { render :xml => @sex, :status => :created, :location => @sex }
      else
        format.html { render :action => "new" }
        format.xml  { render :xml => @sex.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

In models/sex.rb, there is nothing...

```
class Sex < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

**And this is the set up of the database**

[image: and this is my database structure]

Comment: Any chance you're using attr_protected/accessible in the model?

Comment: the model is totally blank . Is that a problem? -- class Sex < ActiveRecord::Base
end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the issue is that you're retrieving `params[:blob]` when you should be looking at `params[:sex]`.  `form_for` will create fields named after the class of the object.  The instance variable name `@blob` you're using is arbitrary.

```
...
@sex = Sex.new(params[:sex])
...
```

This is a good argument for why you probably want to name instance variables for what they are.  Less confusion.

Comment: I just updated the OP with a screen shot of my server trying to do a GET request (when it should have been POST, i think). Is your answer consistent with that? i.e. does my using @blob explain why it was making a get request?

Comment: or is it not a problem that the server was doing a GET (since it was submitted from index...)

Comment: The `GET` is happening after, most likely.  That's the redirect after the record is created.  You want to look at the request before that, which probably is a `POST` passing `:sex => { stuff }`

Comment: the instance variable naming is arbitrary.  It could be `@bananas` or `@barackobama`.  Such naming might lead to confusion, but won't otherwise affect how your code behaves.

Comment: i get that but even if it's arbitrary but sometimes it has to be consistent (in some cases). For example, since I did blob = Sex.new in the Controller, i had to use blob instance variable in the form_for blob in the view.  Therefore, I thought the instance variable turned into the params :blob, but now you explained why...form_for creates fields named after class of object...